# How to specialize template for type derived from particular type

Tags: c++, templates

I have class `World` which manages creation of object... After creation it calls `afterCreation` method and I the created object is user-defined type derived from Entity (eg. `MyEntity`), I want to call `addEntity`. I the object was something else, I want to do nothing.
`addEntity` must be called with appropriate `T`, because it generates unique IDs for every derived class etc.

Here is my solution:

```
template <int v>
struct ToType
{
    enum { value = v };
};

template <typename T>
void World::afterCreation(T * t)
{
    afterCreation(t, ToType<std::is_base_of<Entity, T>::value>());
}

template <typename T>
void World::afterCreation(T * t, ToType<true>)
{
    addEntity(t); //here I cant pass Entity *, I need the real type, eg. MyEntity
}

template <typename T>
void World::afterCreation(T * t, ToType<false>)
{

}
```

My question is - Can in be done better way?

How can I simulate following code without `ToType` or similar?

```
template <typename T>
void afterCreation(){/*generic impl*/}

template <typename T where T is derived from Entity>
void afterCreation(){/*some specific stuff*/}
```

- "specialize" in the title is only to describe my intention, no need to solve problem with template specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not going to make it much better, but you can remove one level of indirection by using SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of<Entity, T>::value >::type
 World::afterCreation(T * t)
{
   // Derived from Entity
}
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_base_of<Entity, T>::value >::type
 World::afterCreation(T * t)
{
   // generic
}
```

How does this work? When the compiler finds the call to `afterCreation` it tries to determine which of the overloads is *best*, and for that it matches the types and tries to perform the substitution. In both cases, the matched type (from the arguments) and apply the substitution to the whole expression. The `enable_if` template contains an inner type `type` if the value passed as the first argument is `true` or else it does not contain such type. During the substitution of the types, one of the overloads will yield an invalid function signature (the one for which the condition is false) and will be dropped from the set of candidates.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with polymorphic pointers:

```
template <typename T>
void afterCreation(T* x) {
    T* entity = dynamic_cast<Entity*> x;

    if (!entity) {
        // ... generic implementation
    } else {
        // ... entity implementation, use "entity"
    }
}
```

Though this might not be the best solution since this has a (tiny) run-time overhead. A very smart compiler might remove this overhead through static analysis but I doubt compilers will pick this up.

Comment: Eddie Edwards: simply by passing the pointer of the object you want it to run on. `Entity x; afterCreation(&x);`.

Comment: +1, simple and to the point :) Solves the actual problem, rather than what the question asks (with a much simpler approach than SFINAE --I am assuming that nothing in the function will only compile for `Entity` derived types, i.e. there is nothing like `entity->getEntityName()` that will fail to compile for non Entity derived types)

Comment: Sorry nightcracker I backed out my comments (and they applied to your unedited answer)
I think a lot of compiler will remove the dynamic_cast since it has full knowledge of the type of x.  Or, at least, as much knowledge as it needs, assuming that the templated solution can work at all.